# Javascript vs C# for dynamically changing element class/id in ASP.NET 4.5 MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, css, asp.net-mvc

I'm new to MVC and still learning, and I would like to know what the convention/best practice is for doing what I described.

I have a menu bar which changes visually based on which page you're on. Currently, I'm doing this with a simple JS .ready() script block at the top of each of my .cshtml view files, and this works just fine. When the page loads it iterates through the menu bar `<ul>` and changes the `<li>` id/classes:

```
@{ ViewBag.Title = "Test Page"; }
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    var listItems = $("#menu-bar li");
    listItems.each(function (li) {
        if ($(this).attr('id') == 'about-link') $(this).addClass('active');
        else $(this).removeClass('active');
    });
});
</script>
<!-- Rest of the .cshtml file... -->
```

I have a distinct feeling however that this is neither elegant nor optimum. So what would be the best way to accomplish this task specifically for MVC (or in general if that's the case).

Thank you!

Comment: can you show your code how are you doing currently?\

Comment: Sure I'll update my question.

Comment: What I usually do is create a jQuery function in my javascript file like `$.makeActive(id)`, so then in each .cshtml file, I put something like `$.makeActive("Home")`, and then the jQuery function just adds the `active` class to the appropriate menu item.  So, something like `$("#" + id + "menuItem").addClass("active-page");`

Comment: @JohnieKarr thanks for the answer, that was going to be the next iteration to my solution, however I realized that would simply be akin to sweeping the clutter under the rug without actually optimizing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Razor to solve this in your Layout.cshtml file.

```
<ul>
    <li class="@ViewBag.Home">Home</li>
    <li class="@ViewBag.About">About</li>
</ul>
```

Then at the top of each view, set the right one to active.

```
@{
    ViewBag.Home = "active";
}
```

Comment: Ah that's nifty, and helps me understand ViewBag better too! Perfect solution!

Comment: No problem. ViewBag is the catch all container for passing data from C# into you HTML that is not part of your model. Keep in mind that the Razor code is executed on the server, so the active tag is already set by the time it reaches the browser. jQuery can only set the tag client side after the page has loaded. The more you can accomplish with server side scripting, the less strain you'll put on the browser.

Comment: Interesting point! My solution is going to be used on mobile so the less client-side overhead the better. Thank you!